# How to prevent an ipad or tablet from switching to portrait mode?

Tags: jquery, html

I am not sure if this is possible or not but i do not want my page to switch orientation when switching to portrait mode. i want it to be locked on landscape mode perminatley.
I hope this makes since.
Any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop Safari from switching orientation, but you can use a CSS `@media` rule to cause the effective screen width to remain the same, however it will mean when moving from portrait-to-landscape that you'll lose vertical pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can't in a web app, but you can in native apps